# How can I use the FreezePanes feature in Excel without getting the lines emanating out from the axis point?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I've got code to configure a "Freeze Pane" on my spreadsheet:

```
private void FreezePane(int rowNum, int colNum)
{
    Excel.Range cellToFreeze = (Excel.Range)_xlSheet.Cells[rowNum, colNum];
    cellToFreeze.Activate();
    cellToFreeze.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
}
```

...which I call like so:

```
FreezePane(DATA_STARTING_ROW, MONTH1_COL);
```

It works as expected; however, I find the lines Excel adds that spread from the freeze point outward a bit distracting/uglifying. Here's what the vertical one looks like, sticking out the top of the freeze point and going, probably, all the way through the stratosphere:

[image]

A horizontal line (not shown) also proceeds past the furthest column, beyond the [furthest city light](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/177009) (to say the least).

Here's more or less what I'd like the sheet to look like (how it looks without the Freeze pane functionality):

[image]

So how can I have my freeze pane without the vertical and horizontal lines scoring the sheet with their to-infinity-and-beyond effect? Or is this a "feature" that I should learn to love, or at least live with?

Comment: AFAIK you can't turn this off.

Comment: I was afeared of that; but, at least if it can't be done, I can't be blamed or expected to clean it up.

Comment: If that's the case (I'm doomed to have the guywires protruding), it'd be nice to "they" (MS) made the lines' presentation morphable, such as tiny dancing bears or frolicking kittens or some such, rather than just a plain black line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the ScrollArea properties instead^

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 'Change the sheet name to whatever your sheet name is
Sheet1.ScrollArea = "A1:R28" 'Set your range to where you want the user to be able to navigate

End Sub
```

Let me know if that help!

Comment: I'm not using VBA; I do it all in C#; in fact, I have switched to EPPlus (was using Excel Interop).